# Error appending while trying to access continuously growing list in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, linq

I am adding web socket elements into List which is growing continuously. I am getting around 70,000 ticks in a minute from web socket. Now I need to use value from that list. But when I am going to access that list it's giving me this error:

> Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.

I have check about this error on google and almost suggestions are referring lock. So I have use there lock but still I am getting that error.
So How can I access data from the list which is growing continuously. I don't want to disturb that list process which is running in web socket side.

websocket side I have just declare list like :

```
public static List<LiveMarketDataObject> liveQuotesList = new List<LiveMarketDataObject>();

...websocket connection and receive message code is here...

liveQuotesList.Add(_liveQuotes);
```

So here it's adding 70,000 records on every minute to liveQuoteList.

And on second side I am trying to access value from that list using linq. But at this point it's showing an error.

```
readonly object _lock = new object();
private static List<LiveMarketDataObject> liveQuotesList = socketWithEvaluation.liveQuotesList;
...
...
lock (liveQuotesList)
{
   var newQuoteList = liveQuotesList.ToList().Where(x => x.sym == symbolName && x.t >= startunixTime && x.t <= endunixTime).ToList();
}
```

when I am trying to copy or when I am trying to access data directly from that list then it's not allow me to access. So how can I access data from list ?

Comment: Why not use `ConcurrentBag<T>`? It's designed to be accessed by multiple threads at once. No need to implement manual locking, just declare the bag and access it. Or, if you're accessing the list using a producer/consumer pattern, try `BlockingCollection<T>`.

Comment: @PatrickTucci, If we use ConcurrentBag instead of List and if we access record from ConcurrentBag then that record will be available ahead or will it be remove from concurrent bag ?

Comment: @Ankit the object will still be present. With `BlockingCollection<T>`, however, when you get an object using `Take()` or `TryTake()`, the collection will remove the object when it gives it to you. Note that `Take()` will block the current thread, which is not necessarily a bad thing. A consumer can "wait" for objects in a producer/consumer pattern.

Comment: means I need to access data from blocking collection and also I need to make it's present there. So what should I use there? If I will use Take then it will remove data from concurrent list.

Comment: No that's not true. You can use [`TryTake()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.trytake?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Concurrent_BlockingCollection_1_TryTake__0__) to see if there's an item available and take it if it is. If not, `TryTake()` will return `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your code to be thread-safe, you should synchronize *all* operations, including the calls to the `Add` method, against the list using the same lock:

```
lock (_lock)
    liveQuotesList.Add(_liveQuotes);

...
lock (_lock)
{
   var newQuoteList = liveQuotesList.Where(x => x.sym == symbolName && x.t >= startunixTime && x.t <= endunixTime).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I have apply lock on both side. At adding elements to list and access list elements. but still it's giving me same error.

Comment: @ankit sample code in the post does not show that. Even worse- lock is in one class and array is in another so it is unlikely one can write it to share the lock

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, so that means should I declare lock object in one class and use it at every place where we need to use it. is it right ?

Comment: @Ankit for the *same piece of data* accessed from multiple threads you must use *the same object* to `lock` on. The simplest approach is to have only one object to `lock` on for all your data, but that will likely cause slow downs due to every thread trying to lock on the same object. You need to decide how *granular* locks need to be in your case.